# VS2017 Cannot resolve GenXbf.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I just create a simple UWP for Win10-IoT

when I build the project , I encountered below problem:

Cannot resolve 'GenXbf.dll'

Cannot resolve 'GenXbf.dll' under path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86\genxbf.dll'.

Please install the latest version of the Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
FirstIoTApp  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86\genxbf.dll

my PC installed with win10 OS pro.  I have these in my Control Panel:

Windows Software Development Kit

windows 10.0
10586.212
14393.33
15063.468
15063.674
16299.15
16299.91
26624

I can not run the App. What I need to do to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try right click on your project file, choose properties, change the minimum version to a previous version. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried to REPAIR either Windows 10.0.15063.00 or 
Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.14393.795 by going to the control panel?

Comment: there could be other issues that are involved - but according to Microsoft, they are aware of some issues with vs2017 and have this to say as far as a workaround goes: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/07/12/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-16232-released/